# How to have params read in Backbone js when including pushState: true?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have the following code but using `pushState: true` does not have the function called anymore, pre-pushstate with a hash it works, but when doing `?q=ok` does not get read, when I had pushState not set `#?q=ok` works.

Here is the code:

```
(function(search,Backbone,$) {
    $(function() {
        app = new search.Views.AppView({
            el: $("[search]")
        });

        var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
            routes: {
                '(?:params*)': function(params) {
                    if (params) {
                        params = QueryString.decode(params);
                    }
                    else {
                        params = {};
                    }

                    if (params.q) {
                        app.setQuery(params.q);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        var router = new Router();
        Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
    });
})(search,Backbone,jQuery);
```